# Блокируется форма после вызова функции метода

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

У меня есть код такого рода:

```
private static StringBuilder building = new StringBuilder();
public static bool Starting(string path, string Code)
{  
   using (var pv = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions))
   {
     pv.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Code); 
   }
   // Много кода ...
   if (File.Exists(path))
   {
      File.WriteAllText("Log.txt", building.ToString());
      return true;
   }
   else { return false; }
}
```

После запуска на кнопке UI замерает на несколько секунд.

Пробовал запустить в отдельном потоке `Thread`

```
var potinizialize = new Thread(() => { Starting("path", "code"); });
potinizialize.Start(); 
potinizialize.Join(); // нужно сделать ожидания завершения метода
```

Но даже это не помогло, форма всё ровно замерает на несколько секунд.

Какие есть возможные вариант использования? Чтобы форма не блокировалась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типичная проблема с забиванием UI потока. Вы, в первом случае забили его операций ввода-вывода. Во втором случае, вы, создали поток и синхронно ждете его окончания. Попробуйте это:

```
var potinizialize = new Thread(() => { Starting("path", "code"); });
```

заменить на:

```
await Task.Run(()=>{Starting("path", "code"); })
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: @GooliveR галочка для принятия ответа слева от ответа, под голосовалкой :)

Comment: А там время нужно чтобы дать галочку. Спасибо)

Comment: @GooliveR а, понял. Ну, как будет время )

Comment: А вот ещё интересно если таких методов пару, то на каждый нужно вещать `await Task.Run(() => { method(); });` ?

Comment: либо на каждый, либо оба запускать в одной таске друг за другом `await Task.Run(()=>{Starting("path", "code");Starting("path", "code");Starting("path", "code");Starting("path", "code"); })`

Comment: ну и я не писал такого, но есть возможность операции ввода-вывода  сделать асинхронными, покинуть UI контекст и не блокировать пул потоков, но это уже продвинутые темы, их долго объяснять. То есть то, что я вам предложил - это рабочий, но не самый оптимальный вариант.